# How to achieve the v2v communication?

Tags: omnet++

I am new in Veins. In my scenario, I use omnetpp-4.6, sumo-0.21.0 and veins-3.0 and there are just two cars, named `node[0]` and `node[1]`. Now I want to implement a scenario in which the `node[0]` sends its position to `node[1]` at 1 times/sec.

Comment: Please check "[How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)." What have you tried on your own? Did you run into any problems?

Answer (score 0):

Repeated sending of messages in Veins is done no different to any other module library for OMNeT++. You can refer, for example, to the OMNeT++ TicToc tutorial for a good introduction. "How to get started" is also covered in the [Veins FAQ](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/faq/):

> The [Veins tutorial](http://sumo-sim.org/userdoc/) has all the necessary information to run a basic simulation of a vehicular network. A high level overview of Veins is given in the [Veins documentation](http://sumo-sim.org/userdoc/). The next steps depend on what you want to do.
>
> For creating own simulations, you will need to learn how to use OMNeT++. Excellent tutorials, videos, and a comprehensive user manual are available on the [documentation pages on the OMNeT++ website](http://sumo-sim.org/userdoc/).
>
> If you know how to use OMNeT++ and want to write custom simulation modules (e.g., for new applications), you might find an API documenation of the Veins simulation module library helpful. It can be created from the IDE, by clicking *Project > Generate NED Documentation...*, or from the command line, by running `make doxy`. To start reading the module documenation, open `doc/index.html` in your browser.
>
> If you use one of the available road traffic scenarios, there is no need to learn much about SUMO. If you want to run your simulations on custom road maps, you will need to learn how to use SUMO, though. SUMO comes with an excellent tutorial (*Hello SUMO*) and an extensive online user manual, available on the [documentation pages on the SUMO website](http://sumo-sim.org/userdoc/).
>
> If you want to implement new TraCI commands for interacting with (or getting data from) the running road traffic simulation, the SUMO TraCI documentation has a list of available commands.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir. I think the TraCIDemo11p.cc file maybe helpful,  I shall try it out.